# How to convert from float to std::wstring

Tags: slider, c++-winrt, winui-3

I want to know the proper way to convert from "Float" to "std::wstring".

Xaml file

```
<Page
    x:Class="TD2_WinUI3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TD2_WinUI3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        
        <Slider AutomationProperties.Name="Slider with ticks" Header="headerString" Width="300" TickFrequency="10" TickPlacement="Outside" ValueChanged="slider_ValueChanged" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="Current value: 0" />
        
    </StackPanel>
    
    
</Page>
```

Cpp File

```
void MainPage::slider_ValueChanged(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs const& args)
{
    std::wstring msg = static_cast<float>(L"Current value: {0:s}", args.NewValue());
    textBlock1().Text(msg);

}
```

That's my piece of code throwing me that error:

```
E0415   no suitable constructor exists to convert from "float" to "std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t>>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
std::wstringstream wss;
wss << 1.4f;
auto result = wss.str(); // what you want
```

Comment: That's how we did things more than a decade ago. C++11 introduced [`std::to_wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring), in other words: `auto const result{ std::to_wstring(1.4f) };`.